# json file does not contain valid JSON

Tags: php, json, magento

I have issue with my `auth.json` file in `magento 2.1.6`

Basically i am using `auth.json` file to connect with `repo.magento.com`

While i m trying to install module via composer than it is giving me error like this

**`auth.json does not contain valid JSON Parse error on line 1`**

Here is my auth.json file

```
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username":"<public key>",
        "password":"<private key>"
    }
}
```

Here is the actual error

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>
> "http-basic": {    "repo.magento.c
>
> ------------^
>
> Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to wrap the whole thing in curly braces to make it a proper json object: `{ "http-basic": .... }`

Comment: Ok i just found the answer 1 min ago. Thank you for help :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you so much for your suggestion :) it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer while i was testing this code in [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/).

The json code should be wrapped by `{}`

It will goes like this.

```
{
    "http-basic": {
       "repo.magento.com": {
           "username":"<public key>",
           "password":"<private key>"
       }
    }
}
```